# Micrsoft Dynamics CRM: Facing trouble while retrieving value from form

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to get values from form and print those value in windows form but whenever I try to save the values it failed showing the error An unexpected error occurred from ISV code.

```cs
 public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
   // Get the context and organization service
   IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IPluginExecutionContext));
   IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IOrganizationServiceFactory));
   IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

   Entity target = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

   try {
     EntityReference lookupValue = target.GetAttributeValue < EntityReference > ("new_contact");
     EntityReference lookupValue2 = target.GetAttributeValue < EntityReference > ("new_account");
     // string contactname = target.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_contact");
     // string accountname = target.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_account");

     MessageBox.Show("" + lookupValue + " " + lookupValue2);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
   }
 }
```

Comment: the code looks like from a plugin, inside a plugin you can't call WinForms UI messages like MessageBox.Show

Comment: is there any alternate of it?

Comment: Are you trying to get the values from a form or form dataverse? I don't think you can call a winforms app from a JS in d365